# Cannot append LI to UL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to be able to add a LI to UL using jQuery. When I click on the button, nothing happens.

Here is a quick fiddle which depicts the problem I am facing:

https://jsfiddle.net/80ugxpx7/2/

The JavaScript and HTML markup in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* declare global variable */

var recent = []

function add_to_recent() {

    var x = document.getElementById('fileno').value

    recent.push(x)

    $("#recent ul").append('<li>'+x+'</li>')

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="fileno" type="text"><input type="button" value="search" onclick="add_to_recent()">
    <br>
    <ul id="recent">

        <li>lol</li>

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no element with the ID `fileno`, just an input with an invalid type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had to move your function around a bit, 
you were mixing Pure JS and Jquery so I've made it all Jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/80ugxpx7/4/

```
<input id="fileno" type="text">
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="add_to_recent()">
<br>
<ul id="recent"></ul>

var recent = []

add_to_recent = function () {
    var x = $('#fileno').val();
    recent.push(x);
    $("#recent").append('<li>' + x + '</li>');
    $('#fileno').val("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
<input id="fileno" type="text">
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="$('#recent').append('<li>'+$('#fileno').val()+'</li>');">
<br>
<ul id="recent">

</ul>
```